# How to get font name to pass to canvas

Tags: node.js, canvas, fonts, node-canvas

I would like to know how to get a name of the font I installed to pass to HTML5 canvas context to set the font.

I am using node-canvas, and trying to set a font to [unleanred](http://www.dafont.com/unlearned.font).

After downloading and installing the font, I tried this to set the font:

```
var canvas = new Canvas(370, 120)
  , ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.font = 'bold 30px unlearned';
ctx.fillText('foo', 25, 45);
```

But the font remains unchanged in the output. When I download some other fonts, say [drafting](http://www.dafont.com/drafting.font), and install it, the above works.

So I think the problem is that I am using a wrong name to reference the font. How can I get the correct name and type?

Comment: Simplest is to check what a DTP program on your OS calls the font (Office document writer, Photoshop, whatever) and then use that name.

Comment: Or, alternatively, because technically you're using web technology: you can define a CSS @font-face with a name that is easy, like "myfont". Then in the canvas, load `ctx.font = "bold 30 myfont";` although of course if you're running this in "not the browser", I have no idea how to load an @font-face in, so npmjs.org might be necessary there

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans When I check in Microsoft Word, I only see one of the fonts that I installed. I have installed ~5 fonts. How can I make the fonts show up?

Comment: did you install 5 fonts, in the same font family, or did you install 5 completely unrelated fonts? Because if they're in the same family (but "light", "regular", "medium", "condensed", etc) then the base name is the name you get. For loading as web content *without @font-face* you can just use that name, and pick the appropriate style and weight.

Comment: That makes sense. But they are all 5 different fonts. Some work and some do not. Only one shows up in Microsoft Word.

Comment: If Word doesn't see the others, it's almost guaranteed nothing else will, either. I'd recommend finding out how you can load them from file for your canvas directly, instead of relying on the OS, by using an @font-face CSS rule.